# SQL Server index performance hindered by variable

Tags: sql-server, indexing

I am using a SQL Server 2008 R2 database with a table that contains on the order of a **billion** rows. I want to get the distinct values of one column during the last 24 hours, so I did this (Query 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT SomeField FROM SomeTable WHERE CreatedOn > '2014-01-28 12:24:00'
```

Note there is an index on **CreatedOn**, but it does not include **SomeField**. This returned immediately. Now, since this is a query I run often, I decided to make it dynamic, so I changed it to (Query 2):

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME = DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE())
SELECT DISTINCT SomeField FROM SomeTable WHERE CreatedOn > @StartDate
```

I was surprised that this query took a long time. (I stopped it after a minute or so.) Then I tried putting the variable inline like this (Query 3):

```
SELECT DISTINCT SomeField FROM SomeTable WHERE CreatedOn > DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE())
```

That was fast again. Looking at the execution plans, Query 1 and 3 are identical and use an Index Seek. But Query 2 does an Index Scan and suggests that I am missing an Index on CreatedOn including SomeField.

Why does checking against a variable suddenly change the effectiveness of the Index?

Comment: [Read This](http://msmvps.com/blogs/robfarley/archive/2010/01/22/sargable-functions-in-sql-server.aspx) for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely reason is that when a value is hard coded, the compiler can use the statistics  to figure out the best query to run.  When using a variable, it doesn't and has to do a scan.  You might see better performance if you try to create a stored proc out if it and run it that way so the server can make use of "[parameter sniffing](http://blogs.technet.com/b/mdegre/archive/2012/03/19/what-is-parameter-sniffing.aspx)".

You can find some more info with others who have seen this issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2293772/t-sql-query-performance-puzzle-why-does-using-a-variable-make-a-difference), [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!msg/microsoft.public.sqlserver.tools/HZ7B02DGhdA/rO0k7510a1AJ) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/313935/why-sql-server-go-slow-when-using-variables).